# Processing JS Embedding Issue

Tags: processing

I created a processing JS code in an external IDE from my HTML and I want to put it on my HTML page. I went through many tutorials but I could not figure out why I have the following problem.

My 600x600 project should look like this:
[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am4Ku.png)

When I embed it on my website it looks like this:
[Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEQjy.png)

This is my HTML:

```
<HTML>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://mhs-robotics.com/style/point-counter.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://mhs-robotics.com/java/processing.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <canvas id="can" width="10px" height="10px" data-processing-sources="https://mhs-robotics.com/java/counter.pde"></canvas>
    </center>
</body>
```

This is my CSS:

```
#can {
width: 600px;
hight: 600px;
margin: auto;
border: 5px solid black;
```

}

Comment: The first thing you should do in cases like this is check your [developer tools](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools) for errors. If you aren't seeing any errors, please start with a more basic sketch and narrow your problem down to a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Good luck.

Comment: I get the error "OTS parsing error: post: Failed to parse table".

Comment: Okay cool, sounds like you have an error to investigate. I'd recommend searching on google. It's really hard for us to help until we see a simplified example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: All it seems to be is a failure to load a font. Could that be what is causing this issue?

Comment: Maybe. What happens when you remove the font? I recommend starting with a simpler sketch and only adding enough code to reproduce the problem, that way you understand exactly what's causing it.

Comment: When I limit the code to 4 10x10 boxes in each corner it still is wrong and looks like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AzJ7jLg_dp4uRq3u13P4OWm25g4zAI2L/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it

I added:

```
void setup() {

  size(600, 600);

}
```